# Sorting 2D Dictionaries In Python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, 2d

Very rusty with Python, and I wish to sort and print a 2D array as below. Populating 2D dictionary with studentName and studentScore. Looping around and adding new items to dictionary. I've added a studentName and studentScore as an example. I'd like to sort and print dataSet by studentName... But unsure how. Any help is appreciated as always...

```
dataSet = {}
position = len(dataSet)
studentName = "Derek"
studentScore = "80%"
dataSet.update({position : {"studentName": studentName, "Score": studentScore }})
```

I would like the output to be something like...

```
Student: Derek -- Score: 80%
```

And naturally, loop through each item in dataSet

Currently using this... But is formatted as the object and is quite ugly!

```
def viewScores(dataSet):
 for x in dataSet:
    for y in dataSet[x]:
        print (y,':',dataSet[x][y])
```

Comment: could you be a little clear and can you give sample input and output

Comment: You can look up many of the related questions - answers are already there.

Comment: So in what way should it be sorted give example with more then one data in it

Comment: @VigneshKalai As stated, I would like to sort by studentName, there just happens to only be one item in dictionary...

Comment: "position" is not very helpful: It always maps a new dict to a fixed key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should review the usage of dictionaries in python... Your problem can be solved like this:

```
def viewScores(dataSet):
 for student in sorted(dataSet.keys()):
    print ("{}: {}".format(student, dataSet[student]))


dataSet = {}
studentName = "Derek"
studentScore = "80%"
dataSet[studentName] = studentScore 
dataSet["Zyline"] = "99%"

print(dataSet) # just to show it works (and it might be sorted in reverse order)

viewScores(dataSet)
```

Furthermore, I would recommend to store the score as number and not as string, and to add the percentage signn only in the print satement.

With your new requirement (duplicate names), I would solve it like this:

```
def viewScores(dataSet):
    for student in sorted(dataSet,  key=lambda x: x["studentName"]):
        print ("Student: {} -- Score {}%".format(student["studentName"], student["studentScore"]))


dataSet = []
studentID = 7
studentName = "Derek"
studentScore = 80
dataSet.append({"studentName": studentName, "studentScore": studentScore, "id": studentID}) 
dataSet.append({"studentName": "Zyline", "studentScore": 99, "id": 42})

print(dataSet) # just to show it works (and it might be sorted in reverse order)

viewScores(dataSet)
```

Comment: I'm really showing my rust. Thank you OBu. The only issue I see is it two "students" have the same name?

Comment: then "student" is a bad key for the dictionary. You can either introduce an id, or just use a list of tuples

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possible solution which sorts by name and then score. As suggested, it would make more sense to store your scores as integers as this would make it a bit easier to sort.

```
def viewScores(dataSet):
    entries = sorted([(dataSet[entry]['studentName'], dataSet[entry]['Score']) for entry in dataSet])

    for name, score in entries:
        print('Student: {} -- Score: {}%'.format(name, score))

dataSet = {}
position = len(dataSet)
studentName = "Derek"
studentScore = 80
dataSet.update({position : {"studentName": studentName, "Score": studentScore }})

position = len(dataSet)
studentName = "Andrew"
studentScore = 90

dataSet.update({position : {"studentName": studentName, "Score": studentScore }})
position = len(dataSet)
studentName = "Andrew"
studentScore = 9
dataSet.update({position : {"studentName": studentName, "Score": studentScore }})

viewScores(dataSet)
```

For this example it would display the following output:

```
Student: Andrew -- Score: 9%
Student: Andrew -- Score: 90%
Student: Derek -- Score: 80%
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should get values of you dictionary using [`.values()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values).

Then, you can easily access `studentName` and `studentScore` for each one. I used [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Finally, sort the values using [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted).

```
valuesDict = dataSet.values()
valuesTuple = [(v["studentName"], v["Score"]) for v in valuesDict]
sortedValues = sorted(valuesTuple)

for student, score in sortedValues:
    print "Student: %s -- Score: %s" % (student, score)
```

Comment: list comprehensions are not needed, you can just iterate the keys.

Comment: @OBu I can not just iterate the keys because keys are integer and corresponding values are dictionaries. This is why I used list comprehension... I do not understand why it deserves downvote.

Comment: @OBu Could you explain more specifically what is wrong, please?

Comment: I'd say the problem was not really in your answer but in the question: The way he used the dictionaries, he would have had only one key - which is pointless. If you remove the unneeded dict, you can just iterate the keys. He clarified afterwareds, that he wanted an id - but that would result in a different data structure.

Comment: In your case, you could just write `for student, score in sorted(valuesDict, key=lambda  k: k['studentName']) and omit the first list comprehension.